Nextauth another table into the default session
I am trying to pass another table into the default session that useSession provides with nextauth.
I will first provide the User Model which and then the code I am using to attempt it.
User Model and other table:
model User {
  id            String    @id @default(cuid())
  name          String?
  email         String?   @unique
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  role         String
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
  roles          Roles[]
}

model Roles {
  name String
  gymId Int
  userId String
  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  gym gym @relation(fields: [gymId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@id([gymId, userId])
  @@index([gymId])
  @@index([userId])
}

With this prisma schema I am trying to import the roles into the session because if I only did user then a user could be admin in one gym but then it would run into problems when he wants to join another one. This way I am ensuring that a user has a respective role for every gym that uses this software.
This is the type for the default session and User
declare module "next-auth" {
  interface Session extends DefaultSession {
    user: DefaultSession["user"] & {
      id: string;
      image: string;
      roles: Roles[];
    };
  }

  interface User {
    id: string;
    image: string;
    roles: Roles[];
  }
}

Roles is being imported directly from the prisma schema types, and I am using a list as they can posses multiple roles.
Finally this is the callback for session:
      session: ({ session, user }) => {
        return {
          expires: session.expires,
          user: {
            id: user.id,
            roles: user.roles,
            image: user.image,
          },
        };
      },

Whenever I try to access the session in the front end I am getting the expires, the id, and the image but no the roles.
If you need more information feel free to ask I am new to asking these kinds of question and don't know what kind of information is usually included, thank you in advance to anyone who helps.
Setup:
nextjs pages router.
nextauth js for security with advanced initialization so I can pass in parameters for the SignUp.
database sessions.
